# need explanation of javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a code snippet, which have css, javascript, and html.

this is the full code

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://snipplicious.com/css/bootstrap-3.2.0.min.css">
<style>
.tree li {
    margin: 0px 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px 5px 0px 5px;
}
.tree li::before {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 1px;
    height: 100%;
    right: auto;
    left: -20px;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    bottom: 50px;
}
.tree li::after {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 20px;
    right: auto;
    left: -20px;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.tree li a {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #666;
    font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
    font-size: 11px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
}
/*Remove connectors before root*/
 .tree > ul > li::before, .tree > ul > li::after {
    border: 0;
}
/*Remove connectors after last child*/
 .tree li:last-child::before {
    height: 30px;
}
/*Time for some hover effects*/

/*We will apply the hover effect the the lineage of the element also*/
 .tree li a:hover, .tree li a:hover+ul li a {
    background: #c8e4f8;
    color: #000;
    border: 1px solid #94a0b4;
}
/*Connector styles on hover*/
 .tree li a:hover+ul li::after, .tree li a:hover+ul li::before, .tree li a:hover+ul::before, .tree li a:hover+ul ul::before {
    border-color: #94a0b4;
}
</style>
<script src="http://snipplicious.com/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://snipplicious.com/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>$(function () {
    $('.tree li').on('click', function (e) {
        var children = $(this).find('> ul > li');
        if (children.is(":visible")) children.hide('fast');
        else children.show('fast');
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <h1>Bootstrp tree view - click to hide</h1>
  <div class="tree">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Parent</a>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Child</a>
            <ul>
              <li> <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Child</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Grand Child</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
                <ul>
                  <li> <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                  </li>
                  <li> <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                  </li>
                  <li> <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Grand Child</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

this is javascript code that I ask you to explain

```js
<script>$(function () {
    $('.tree li').on('click', function (e) {
        var children = $(this).find('> ul > li');
        if (children.is(":visible")) children.hide('fast');
        else children.show('fast');
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});</script>
```

> **my question are**
>
> 1. from javascript code on above, what the value of "e" in function(e), and where the value which will input into "e" come from?
> 2. how to convert javascript code on above to a function?, i have been 
>      trying this

```
function showHide(e) {
    var children = $(this).find('> ul > li');
    if (children.is(":visible")) children.hide('fast');
    else children.show('fast');
    e.stopPropagation(); }
```

> but it didnt work

**UPDATE**

this is my code after following Ze Rubeus and A.Wollff

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<style>
.tree li {
    margin: 0px 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px 5px 0px 5px;
}
.tree li::before {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 1px;
    height: 100%;
    right: auto;
    left: -20px;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    bottom: 50px;
}
.tree li::after {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 20px;
    right: auto;
    left: -20px;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.tree li a {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #666;
    font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
    font-size: 11px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
}
/*Remove connectors before root*/
 .tree > ul > li::before, .tree > ul > li::after {
    border: 0;
}
/*Remove connectors after last child*/
 .tree li:last-child::before {
    height: 30px;
}
/*Time for some hover effects*/

/*We will apply the hover effect the the lineage of the element also*/
 .tree li a:hover, .tree li a:hover+ul li a {
    background: #c8e4f8;
    color: #000;
    border: 1px solid #94a0b4;
}
/*Connector styles on hover*/
 .tree li a:hover+ul li::after, .tree li a:hover+ul li::before, .tree li a:hover+ul::before, .tree li a:hover+ul ul::before {
    border-color: #94a0b4;
}
</style>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
    

    function showHide(e) {
        var children = $(this).find('> ul > li');
        if (children.is(":visible")) children.hide('fast');
        else children.show('fast');
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
    
    $('.tree li').on('click', showHide);
    
//$(function () {
//    
//    
//    $('.tree li').on('click', function (e) {
//        var children = $(this).find('> ul > li');
//        if (children.is(":visible")) children.hide('fast');
//        else children.show('fast');
//        e.stopPropagation();
//    });
//});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <h1>Bootstrp tree view - click to hide</h1>
  <div class="tree">
    <ul>
        <li >
        <a href="#">Parent</a>
        <ul>
            <li >
            <a href="#">Child</a>
            <ul>
              <li> <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li >
            <a href="#">Child</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Grand Child</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
                <ul>
                    <li > <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                  </li>
                  <li > <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                  </li>
                  <li > <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li ><a href="#">Grand Child</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

thanks mate^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The e can be used to obtain specific information about the click (left, right or center; coordinates clicked; DOM object clicked on) and this is a `Jquery` syntax not a `Javascript`

```
  <script>$(function () {
        $('.tree li').on('click', function (e) {
            var children = $(this).find('> ul > li');
            if (children.is(":visible")) children.hide('fast');
            else children.show('fast');
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
    });</script>
```

and for the second question , this is not a JavaScript syntax  ($(this).find('> ul > li');) :

```
function showHide(e) {
    var children = $(this).find('> ul > li');
    if (children.is(":visible")) children.hide('fast');
    else children.show('fast');
    e.stopPropagation(); }
```

any way even if it was a JS syntax you'll need to call your function like so and gave a value to e but this makes no seance with your code  :

```
showHide(e);
```

or you can use an IIFE (Immediately-invoked function expression) like the following :

```
(function(){
  var children = $(this).find('> ul > li');
        if (children.is(":visible")) children.hide('fast');
        else children.show('fast');
        e.stopPropagation(); } 
}(e));
```

other solution to adabte your function with the code above :

```
$(function () {
    $('.tree li').on('click', showHide);
});

function showHide(e) {
    var children = $(this).find('> ul > li');
    if (children.is(":visible")) children.hide('fast');
    else children.show('fast');
    return false;
}
```

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/p4149wtv/1/)**

Comment: @stacheldraht27 `$('.tree li').on('click', showHide);`

Comment: @Ze Rubeus thank you so much dude, i still confuse about the "e" thing, what "e" thing called in jquery?, so I can browse it , thanks thanks thanks ^^

Comment: e can be used to obtain specific information about the click (left, right or center; coordinates clicked; DOM object clicked on)

Comment: @stacheldraht27 `e` is jQuery event, passed by default as parameter of handler function. `e.originalEvent` would return the DOM API event, like if you use javascript methods to bind event

Comment: @A.Wolff thanks ,but $('.tree li').on('click', showHide); this code not work on mine

Comment: @stacheldraht27 If has posted in your question `$('.tree li').on('click', function (e) {...});` works, then `$('.tree li').on('click', showHide);` should work. Context would be the same for `this` and event would be first parameter of `showHide(e)` method

Comment: `$('.tree li').on('click', showHide(e));` will use the returned value of `showHide` method as handler, which in this case is undefined

Comment: @ZeRubeus , yeah i have tree class, i didnt change anything beside javascript section on code on above

Comment: @A.Wolff wait wait, ill post my code in my question

Comment: @ZeRubeus i have been updating the code, did i miss something? thank you

Comment: @stacheldraht27 It works as expected here: http://jsfiddle.net/phjx7e7p/  That's said, you should prevent default behaviour too to avoid page scrolling to top, you can use `return false;` as shorthand for both, stopPropagtion and preventDefault: http://jsfiddle.net/phjx7e7p/1/

Comment: well spotted @A.Wolff  bravo ;)

Comment: @A. Wolff , oh silly me, i forgot to put  $('.tree li').on('click', showHide); inside $(function () { }); sorry

Comment: @A.Wolff , this my last question, how to trigger it if i use onclick in html?, thanks both of you are kind person

Comment: @ZeRubeus , this my last question, how to trigger it if i use onclick in html?, thanks both of you are kind person

Comment: html tag ? you want target the html instead of .tree li you mean  ?

Comment: @ZeRubeus umm for example `<li><a onclick="showAlertInJs()">this will show an alert</a></li>` like that

Comment: @A.Wolff i mean call it from html section, is that possible?

Comment: To trigger `onclick` set in HTML markup, call native DOM API method `click()` on element, e.g, `$('li a[onclick]').get(0).click()` **but** better is to call method directly then: `showAlertInJs()`.  Now it is really depending use case, this is kind of too broad question

Answer (score 0):

The snippet is jQuery, not pure javascript. The wrapper,

```
$(function () {
...
});
```

ensures the page has finished loading the DOM before execution. This is necessary when attaching event handlers, as this snippet does:

```
$('.tree li').on('click', function (e) {
...
}
```

Attaches an "onclick" event handler to all list items with a parent of class "tree". The "e" argument refers to the element which triggered the event.

The rest is basic jQuery DOM manipulation.

I don't really understand what you mean by "convert to a function". This snippet sets up an event handler, it's something you do once. Why do you need to convert it to a function? Unless you're talking about converting it to a pure javascript function, which is something entirely different.

Comment: thanks for your explanation , this help me a lot. because im still a noob in javascript area, so  i need it to be javascript function, then i can put the function as a result of one condition. eg :<?php if(condition) ? jsFunctionShow() : jsFunctionHide() ?> .

Answer (score 0):

'`e`' comes from the '`click`' event.. the *clicked target*

If you want to make the script a function may be you can do something like this..

```
<script>
$('.tree li').on('click', function (e) {
        showHide(e);
        e.stopPropagation();
});

function showHide(e){
        var children = $(this).find('> ul > li');
        if (children.is(":visible")) children.hide('fast');
        else children.show('fast');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> from javascript code on above, what the value of "e" in function(e),
>   and where the value which will input into "e" come from?

e is an alias variable of `event` object which has properties giving information about type of event, target element which triggered the element and other info

> how to convert javascript code on above to a function?, i have been
>   trying this

The code snippet in your example is using `jQuery` JavaScript library. $ is just another alias of `jQuery` global object created in JS once you include that library.

```
function showHide(e) {
    var children = $(this).find('> ul > li');
    if (children.is(":visible")) children.hide('fast');
    else children.show('fast');
    e.stopPropagation(); 
}
```

Here you're just defining a function, you need to actually bind it to some event, in your case `click` on `li` element. As you're using $ and other jQuery API inside your showHide, you need to use jQuery to bind an event handler as mentioned by you

```
$('tree li').on('click',showHide);
```

If you can write your code inside showHide() in pure JS, then you can attach event on some element like this

```
document.getElementById('myLi').addEventListener('click', showHide, false);
```